# Object oriented python: calling a class with method(self, *optargs) and receiving error "takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)"

Tags: python

I am working with a piece of python code that looks something like this:

```
#script.py

from module import moduleobject

class classname(moduleobject):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def lookupFunction(self, **optargs):
        data =self.moduleobjectfunction(param1, param2, param3, **optargs)
        return data
```

I want to return the results of `lookupFunction()` with my own parameters in `**optargs`, let's call it `arg1`.

In my shell, I've written the following:

```
from script import classname
a = classname()
a.lookupFunction(arg1)
```

My goal is to return the results of `self.moduleobjectfunction(param1, param2, param3, arg1)`, however, I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: moduleobjectfunction() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`

How do I interpret this? 3 parameters, `param1, param2, param3` are hard-coded while I am only passing `arg1`-- I'm not sure where the issue is with argument mismatches.

Comment: Your call `self.moduleobjectfunction(param1, param2, param3, **optargs)` will pass at least 3 arguments, more if there are `optargs`, but `moduleobjectfunction` only accepts 1. The error message also counts the implicit `self` which adds 1 to the number.

Comment: Where is your definition of moduleobjectfunction(). Further you are trying to pass in param1 param2 and param3 but they are not passed into lookupfunction()

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to be more specific without seeing `moduleobject.moduleobjectfunction` because the exception you've provided is caused by mismatch between how the method `moduleobjectfunction` is defined and called. It apparently only takes two (positional) arguments, meaning instance of `self` and one more argument you pass to it.

Looking at your examples, I'd venture a guess and that is there is some confusion regarding `*name` collecting all remaining positional arguments and `**name` receiving keyword arguments (which may or may not also be what happens around `moduleobjectfunction`).

```
def f1(*args): ...
# is called
f1(val1, val2, ...)
```

But:

```
def f2(**kwargs): ...
# is called
f2(arg1=val1, arg2=val2, ...)
```

Same applies when just passing the arguments through. Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists and https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments.

---

There are few other questions that provided examples raise even though they are not directly related to what you're asking. Like:

- `param[1-3]` not being defined.
- In `from script import classname()` the parenthesis should not be there.
- Also if you completely override/wipe (rather then use or extend) constructor from the super class, was it really how they should have been related?